# ListView DisplayMemberPath Template Bug?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, controltemplate

I am wondering if anyone know something about this issue. It seems like the default template provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms788747.aspx) for ListViewItem does not support `DisplayMemberPath` of ListView.

Example

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

will not display the items as expected. It will work if I replace the `GridViewRowPresenter` with a `ContentPresenter`. So my workaround to write a fully working template is to write a DataTrigger for `DisplayMemberPath` with `Value=""` and there I set the Template to a Template containing the GridViewRowPresenter. If I will not do this a GroupStyle with ItemsPresenter will not work.

My Question: Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486905/302677)

The `DisplayMemberPath` property is actually a shortcut that will tell WPF to create the default item template with nothing more than a `TextBlock` with it's Text bound to whatever field is in `DisplayMemberPath`

If you overwrite the item template in addition to setting `DisplayMemberPath`, then you are essentially overwriting the template that `DisplayMemberPath` created for you, so that property becomes useless.