# WPF Groups of controls

Tags: c#, wpf

For example i have such xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="SwitchingControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton Content="First"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Content="Second"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Content="Third"></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="First" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
                <Label Content="Second" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
                <Label Content="First" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                <Label Content="Second" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
                <Label Content="Third" Grid.Row="4"></Label>
                <Label Content="Third" Grid.Row="5"></Label>
                <Label Content="Second" Grid.Row="6"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I need to show labels which have content `First` is `First` `RadioButton` is checked. Labels which have content `Second` if `Second RadioButton` is checked.
The main problem that number of labels acn be 70-100. Is there some elegant easy way to implement it?

Comment: Are you binding to a viewmodel or code-behind?  Where do all these labels come from?

Comment: @leetibbett,ViewModel

Comment: structure of WPF suggests that even if only Radio button *first* would be chosen - all labels rowDefinition would be shown (might hide them but not remove row definition). If labels represent dynamic data - it`s better to use DataGrid with the Data Trigger (although that might be much trickier than use code behind binding).

Comment: Since you want both a collection of data, and to track the selected data item, I would suggest using a ListBox styled to use RadioButtons. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28571411/302677) for an example.